# How to write interesting Vue.js slider component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have to make Vue.js slider component like this: [Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGlKo.png)

I'm newbie in Vue.js so i don't really understand how to make such functional and embed into already build project, so give me please some advices how to write and embed it, or maybe there is some ready-made solutions that i can use like an example or just embed into my project?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You can provide some code in that case.

Comment: Yep, I found already made component and changed css, here it is: https://vuejsexamples.com/very-simple-vue-slider-bar-component/